# What is difference between pattern and ^pattern$ regEx in java?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

What is the difference between following two regEx ? both matches exact string in java.

```
System.out.println("true".matches("true"));
System.out.println("true".matches("^true$")); // ^ means should start and $ means should end. So it should mean exact match true. right ?
```

Both prints **true**.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to see the **difference** in your selected string.

Try using: - `"afdbtrue"` or `"tru"` with both of them. Both strings would not match the first pattern.

`^true*` -> This means the string should start with `t` (`Caret(^)` means start of string), followed by `r` and `u`, and there can be 0 or more `e` after `tru` (`u*` means 0 or more u)

```
System.out.println("tru".matches("^true*"));     // true
System.out.println("trueeeee".matches("^true*"));// true
System.out.println("asdtrue".matches("^true*")); // false

System.out.println("tru".matches("true"));       // false
System.out.println("truee".matches("true"));   // false
System.out.println("asdftrue".matches("true"));  // false
```

- Your `first and second` sysout will print `true`, because `tru` starts with `t` and there is `0` `e` after `tru`. Same with `trueee`. That will be fine
- Your 3rd sysout will print `false`, because `asdtrue` does not start with `t`
- Your 4th sysout, will again pring `false` because it is not exactly `true`
- Your `5th and 6th` sysouts will again print `false`, because they does not exactly matches `true`

---

**UPDATE**: -

After **OP changed** the question: -

- `^(caret)` matches at the start of the string
- `$(Dollar)` matches at the end of the string.

So, `^true$` will match the string with starting with `true` and ending with `true`.
So, now in this case, there won't be any difference between, `true` and `^true$` in the way you are using.

`str.matches("true")` will match a string that is exactly `"true"`., and
`str.matches("^true$")` will also match exactly `"true"`, because it starts with and ends with `"true"`.

```
System.out.println("true".matches("^true$"));     // true
System.out.println("This will not match true".matches("^true$"));   // false
System.out.println("true".matches("true"));       // true
System.out.println("This will also not match true".matches("true")); // false
```

---

**UPDATE**: -

However, if you use `Matcher.find` method, then there will be a difference in the two pattern. Try this: -

```
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("true").matcher("This will be true");
    Matcher matcher1 = Pattern.compile("^true$").matcher("This won't be true"); 

    if (matcher.find()) {  // Will find
        System.out.println(true);
    } else {
        System.out.println(false);
    }
    if (matcher1.find()) {  // Will not find
        System.out.println(true);
    } else {
        System.out.println(false);
    }
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
true
false
```

- See [Matcher documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for more details on these methods. ([Matcher#find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) and [Matcher#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29))

Comment: @PriyankDoshi. Oh. then `$` means `end` of the string. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 0):

`^` represents the start of the string

`$` represents end of the string

`matches` method **Returns only true if the WHOLE string can be matched**

So,both `"true"` & `"^true$"` would match only a single word i.e `true`

---

But if you use `find` method then following would be valid
So,
`"true"` would match those lines that contain true anywhere

```
Is it true//match
How true//match
true is truth//match
not false//no match
```

`"^true$"`
would match any line that that has only one word that is `true`

```
true//match
true is truth//no match
it is true//no match
```

Comment: System.out.println("it true is".matches("true")); prints false.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi check out the edit..i interpreted `matches` as `find`